# offset() is undefined 'error'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

While loading a page, I want to get the top of the panel. But it is showing errors.
In Firefox and IE its saying "**offset() is undefined**" and in Chrome the error is "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined**". Please Help out.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    tabPanelAdjust();
});

function tabPanelAdjust() {
    var theTabPanel = $(".TabPanel");
    var tabPanelTop = parseInt(theTabPanel.offset().top);
    var winHeight = $(document).height();
    tabPanelHeight = winHeight - tabPanelTop;
    theTabPanel.css({ "min-height": tabPanelHeight - 20 });
}

<div class="TabPanel">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're loading jQuery? Is your script running on document ready? Does `.TabPanel` exist at that point in execution?

Comment: Yes jQuery is loading. and Script is under document ready. But yes, .TabPanel doesn't exist at the point in execution.

Comment: @arpit1611 "Yes jQuery is loading. and its under document ready." What do you mean by that.

Comment: @JaiPSah Edited. I mean to say that .TabPanel doesn't exist at the point of execution.

Comment: just posted an answer check that if it works for you.

Comment: Thnx guys.. problem solved...!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code. include your code within document ready method. May be your code is fired before the div is loaded.

```
$(function(){
$(window).resize(function () {
  tabPanelAdjust();
});

function tabPanelAdjust() {
 var theTabPanel = $(".TabPanel");
 var tabPanelTop = parseInt(theTabPanel.offset().top);
 var winHeight = $(document).height();
 tabPanelHeight = winHeight - tabPanelTop;
 theTabPanel.css({ "min-height": tabPanelHeight - 20 });
}
});
```

Here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SX5U4/

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jsbin.com/ecumag/1/edit

```
function tabPanelAdjust() {
   var theTabPanel = $(".TabPanel");
   alert(theTabPanel.offset().top);
   var tabPanelTop = theTabPanel.offset().top;
   var winHeight = $(document).height();
   tabPanelHeight = winHeight - tabPanelTop;
   theTabPanel.css({ "min-height": tabPanelHeight - 20,"background":"yellow" });
}

$(function(){

    tabPanelAdjust();

});
```

**and please make sure you are loading the jquery**